# request ajax doesn't work with php validation

Tags: php, ajax, validation

I want to use `ajax` in order to `fadeIn` a loader during PHP validation and returning the values from it to show visual effect messages, then `fadeOut` the loader when it finishes. But I did not managed to get a simple return from PHP validation in the `.done function`.

Can anyone help me please?

**Index**

```
<form action="php/valid.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
    <input id="name-contact" class="uk-input uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input id="email-contact" class="uk-input uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
    <textarea id="message-contact" class="uk-input uk-textarea uk-width-1-1 uk-margin-small" name="message" placeholder="Message" style="height:200px"></textarea>
    <button id="contact-btn" class="uk-margin-small uk-button uk-button-secondary uk-width-1-1" type="submit" name="contact-form">Send</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var     data = {
        name: $('#name-contact').val(),
        email: $('#email-contact').val(),
        message: $('#message-contact').val()
    };
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/valid.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                    console.log('Success !');
            } else if (data.status == 'error') {
                    console.log('Error !');
            }
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP file**

```
<?
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $error = false;
    $regex_name = '#^[\w\s\p{L}-]{2,30}$#iu';
    $regex_message = '#^[\s\S]{3,800}$#i';
    if (isset($_POST['contact-form'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $from = $_POST['email'];
        $message = nl2br($_POST['message']);
        if (!empty($name) && !empty($from) && !empty($message)) {
               if (preg_match($regex_name, $name) && filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match($regex_message, $message)) {
                    $error = array('type' => 'success');
               } else {
                    $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'There are some errors, please check your informations.');
               }
        } else {
            $error = array('type' => 'error', 'value' => 'Some fields are empty, please check your informations.');
        }
    }
    if (isset($error['type']) && $error['type'] == 'success') {
        $return_status['status'] = 'success';
        echo json_encode($return_status);
    }
    else {
        if (isset($error['type']) && $error['type'] == 'error') {
            $return_status['status'] = 'error';
            echo json_encode($return_status);
        }
     }
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what happens when you run your code? Checked the console for errors? Done a `console.log(data);` in the top of your `done()` callback? Also, you should add a `event.preventDefault()` right before you do your ajax request (in the callback for your click event) or it will simply do a regular post to the page and your ajax code would never run.

Comment: Btw, the `data` variable will be set on page load. You should probably move that inside the click event or all values will always be empty.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson l change code as the first answer but still have an object error : Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ......

Comment: `readyState: 4` only means that the request is done and doesn't tell us anything else. If you get that in your `fail()`-callback, then open up the browsers developer tools and go to the "Network"-tab. Make a request and check what the request looks like and what the server returns (the response).

Comment: I would also recommend using a relative url from the root folder. You do that by starting the url with a slash: `url: '/php/valid.php',` if the folder `php` is in your web root. If it's not, just add the complete path from the web root: `url: '/path/to/php/valid.php',`

Comment: Well it's weird because if I remove the preventDefault it naturally redirects me to application/json and the answer is correct, but if it's set, it it puts me an error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: I tried to add : contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
and change data to : data: JSON.stringify(data)
But don't work!

Comment: You might have some white space before or after the output that messes it up. Make sure there's no space/line breaks before the opening tag. You should also change the opening tag to `<?php` instead of the short tag `<?` (since that's disabled on many systems). You should also remove the last `?>`. That makes sure there's no accidental white spaces after the output. Also `stringify` creates a string of the json object. You want it to be json so don't do that.

Comment: I did what you said but nope! Haha, makes me crazy and have no idea where's the problem lol. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from being submitted normally.

Second, you need to get the values of the inputs in the event handler. Your code is setting `data` when the page is loaded, before the user has filled in the form.

Third, your PHP script checks for the `contact-form` parameter. This is sent when you submit the form normally, but your AJAX request isn't setting it. You need to add it to `data`, or remove `if (isset($_POST['contact-form']))` from the PHP (if `valid.php` is never used for anything else, this check is probably not necessary).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      name: $('#name-contact').val(),
      email: $('#email-contact').val(),
      message: $('#message-contact').val(),
      "contact-form": true
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/valid.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'success') {
          console.log('Success !');
        } else if (data.status == 'error') {
          console.log('Error !');
        }
      })
      .fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I still have the same object error : Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .....
And nothing happens, even not console.log(data). Do you have an idea?

Comment: Check the AJAX response in the Network tab, make sure there's nothing extra around the JSON.

Comment: Returning SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: All those nested `if` statements in the PHP are very confusing. Maybe there's a path through them that never echoes any JSON.

Comment: What do you see in the Response section of the Network tab?

Comment: It's weird because if I remove the preventDefault it naturally redirects me to application/json and the answer is correct from JSON in the response Network tab, but if preventDefault is set, the response is this error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data... So l don't understand

Comment: That can't be the response from the server. That's a JavaScript error, not something PHP sends. You can't possibly see that in he Response tab when viewing the AJAX call. What do you see in the request headers and the raw response?

Comment: Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/sae/contact_form/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 21
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: We're more interested in the POST parameters being sent. It appears in the "Form Data" section below the headers.

Comment: In paramaters l have this : name=Joe&email=my%40mail.com&message=Test

Comment: You're not sending the `contact-form` parameter in the AJAX request, and the code starts with `if (isset($_POST['contact-form']))`

Comment: Yep when I remove isset() the response is still in error JSON parse with this : <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: contact-form in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\contact

Comment: What is `\xampp\htdocs\SAE\contact`? The script we're working on is `php/valid.php`.

Comment: That error can't happen if you removed all references to `$_POST['contact-form']`

Comment: This is a localhost project at this time

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? We're trying to debug `valid.php`, why are you showing me an error from `contact`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180545/discussion-between-barmar-and-joe278).

Answer (score 0):

Change button type to button:

```
<button id="contact-btn" class="" type="button" name="contact-form">Send</button>
```

Change your js code like below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contact-btn').click(function(event) {
        var data = {
            name: $('#name-contact').val(),
            email: $('#email-contact').val(),
            message: $('#message-contact').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/valid.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == 'success') {
                        console.log('Success !');
                } else if (response.status == 'error') {
                        console.log('Error !');
                } else
                    console.log("Somthing went wrong....")
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
              }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I still have the same object error : Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ..... And nothing happens, even not console.log(data). Do you have an idea?